# Are there better ways of inserting HTML into the DOM than insertAdjacentHTML() and a huge HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to insert a large amount of HTML into the DOM.

My current way of doing this is copy-pasting the HTML I need to insert into a JS file, formatting it such that it's bug-free within the string, and then using `insertAdjacentHTML()` to insert.

Having a huge, multi-line string of copy-pasted HTML in the JS just feels dirty every time I happen to scroll through it.

The only constraint is that I really want to avoid using libraries if I can.

Better in this case is pretty much a secure implementation that's an improvement in readability.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what, if any, additional processing is required on your string before insertion, or what "dirty" means from a practical perspective.

Comment: Keep the contents in html file, make an AJAX call to fetch the contents of file and use for DOM manipulation(insertion, iterative additions..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't wish to use a HTML templating tool, you can still include the HTML in a similar manner.

The [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) site includes some examples, such as including the HTML in the .html file itself, selecting the element, and parsing its contents:

---

> You can deliver a template to the browser by including it in a  tag.

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

> Compile a template in JavaScript by using Handlebars.compile

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

---

In your case, you could replace the `type` property in the html to anything obvious, and retrieve the contents by calling `document.querySelector("htmlString").innerHTML`.

Other options include loading the HTML as a separate file via AJAX, or if you're daring, writing your own transpiler to stick the HTML in the Javascript for you (which is basically what React does with JSX)

One last thing to consider: you will want to ensure that the injected HTML doesn't include any potential XSS vulnerabilities or that any DOM events won't get screwed up as a result of adding the HTML (though using `insertAdjacentHTML` should prevent events from breaking).

Also, consider looking over this HTML injection code I wrote awhile back to ensure you're avoiding (some but not all) possible pitfalls:
https://github.com/jsweeneydev/HTMLTemplate/blob/master/htmltemplate.js

Good luck!

Comment: thought the OP didnt want to use a library? is there a better way to do this nowadays?